# Can't sideload some apps on some kernels (idlekernel, Cyanogenmod kernel)

Tags: applications, installation, kernel, side-loading

I always wanted to use idlekernel but once I install it, the apps would disappear (also happened on Cyanogenmod kernel). Usually the apps that it doesn't want me to sideload are the ones that gets installed on `/mnt/apsec`. Even apps that comes from the Play Store and/or Amazon are not allowed to install.

I know I can just move the apps from `/mnt/asec` to the phone storage to access them again but installing apps that require to have their data on `/mnt/asec` will again not be installed.

Why are there kernels that don't allow me to sideload "some" apps? Is there a workaround here?